# HTTP 404 Description The origin server did not find a curnt representation for the target resource / is not willing to disclse tht 1 exists

Tags: java, apache, servlets, tomcat9, mssql-jdbc

HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/nivi%20/register] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.52

Comment: It is very unlikely for a context path to contain a space (`/nivi ` vs `/nivi`), therefore the space character was probably added in your code.

Comment: While this is already solved as duplicate: Please read [ask] and take the [tour] before you post your next question: Just dumping an error message does not make a proper question.